# How can I tab dynamically with capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara

I am testing a web app with multiple dynamic rows.  With nothing to scope and grab in the vicinity.  I get to the particular field by grabbing something I can id, and tabbing to the text box or selector I wish to manipulate.

It looks like this...

```
editor = page.find_by_id('grabbable')
editor.native.send_keys(:tab, :tab, "Hello World")
```

What I'd like to do is something like...

```
tab_amount = tabs(2)

editor = page.find_by_id('grabbable')
editor.native.send_keys(tab_amount, "Hello World")
```

...

```
def tabs(amount)
  tab_object = :tab
  while amount > 1
    tab_object = tab_object + :tab
    amount = amount - 1
  end
  return tab_amount
end
```

Is such a dynamic tab possible?

Comment: If you the field is 2 tabs over, why not use an xpath or css selector to get the desired field? For example, if the desired text field is a sibling and two input fields after grabbable, you could use `page.find(:xpath, '//*[@id="grabbable"]/following-sibling::input[2]').set('Hello World')`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up doing...

```
def autotab(amount)
tab = Array.new 
amount.times do
    tab << :tab
end
return tab
end
```

Answer (score 3):

what about something like

```
def tabs(amount)
  tab_object = Array.new(amount, :tab)
end
```

`editor.native.send_keys(*tabs(3), "Hello World")`

some info on splat here

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/doc/syntax/calling_methods_rdoc.html#label-Array+to+Arguments+Conversion